# cURL, cat, python and missing parts from a web page

Tags: python, curl, encoding, cat

I have downloaded a web page(`charset=iso-8859-1`) using `curl`

```
curl "webpage_URL" > site.txt
```

The encoding of my terminal is `utf-8`. Here I try to see the encoding of this file:

```
file -i site.txt
site.txt: regular file
```

Now: the strange thing: If I open the file with `nano` I find all the words that are visible in a normal browser. BUT when I use:

```
cat site.txt
```

some words are missing. This fact makes me curious and after some hours of research I didn't figure out why.

In python too, it does't find all the words:

```
def function(url):
   p = subprocess.Popen(["curl", url], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   output, err = p.communicate()
   print output
   soup=BeautifulSoup(output)
   return soup.body.find_all(text=re.compile('common_word'))
```

I also tried to use `urllib2` but I had no success.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried cat -A file.txt ?

Comment: It works with `cat -v site.txt`

Comment: I wrote `cat -v` instead of `cat -A` because, at least my version of cat doesn't have the `-A` option.

Comment: yes, looked like that could be solved using cat options :)
Best Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody will face the same problem:

The root of my problem were some carriage return characters (`\r`) that are present in the web page. The terminal cannot print them. This wouldn't be a big problem, but the whole line that contains a `\r` is skipped.

So, in order to see the content of the entire file: this characters should be escaped with the `-v` or `-e`  option:

```
cat -v site.txt
```

(thanks to MendiuSolves who has suggested to use the cat command options)

In order to solve a part of the python problem: I changed the return value from `soup.body.find_all(text=re.compile('common_word'))` to `soup.find_all(text=re.compile('common_word'))`

It is obvious that if the word you search for is on one of the line containing a `\r` and you will print it you will not see the result. The solution could be either filter the character or write the content in a file.